# how to get a result of String[] for position

Tags: java, arrays, string

i am using Universal Image Loader and get data from url.
but i dont know how to get a result of String[] for position.

my code as follow. it show the an mistake"The value of the local variable IMAGES is not used"

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_monster_list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText("this is number "+ (position+1)+"photo" );

        imageLoader.displayImage(IMAGES[position], holder.image, options, animateFirstListener);

        return view;
    }

class showTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://garyhui86.er-webs.com/monstersxml.php");
            HttpURLConnection urlConn = 
                                 (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            if (urlConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory
                        .newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
                Document document = builder.parse(urlConn.getInputStream());
                NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("Info");
                for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                    NamedNodeMap attributes=nodeList.item(i).getAttributes();
                    String monstersname=attributes.getNamedItem("monsters_name").getNodeValue();
                    String monstersimage=attributes.getNamedItem("monsters_image").getNodeValue();
                    Log.i("ttt", monstersname);
                    categoryList.add(monstersname);
                    Monsters_image.add(monstersimage);
                }
            }
            urlConn.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        String[] IMAGES = Monsters_image.toArray(new String[Monsters_image.size()]);
    }

}
```

Comment: You should add the according programming language tag.

Comment: Yes you are right. I guess that is java, right? I'll add that tag.

Comment: @Filburt I added the tag along with `array`, seen as the questions mentions a problem with a `String[]`.

Comment: "The value of the local variable IMAGES is not used" is not an error, it's a warning. You want to get a string array for positions of what?

Comment: i want the images[positions] for imageLoader.displayImage in Universal Image Loader

Comment: i have added more detail in the code, can some teach me how to make use of the "IMAGE" for IMAGE[positions] ?

Comment: What do you mean by "get a result of `String[]` for position"?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english... the problem of my apps is the"IMAGES" in onPostExecute showing a warning"The value of the local variable IMAGES is not used" and the "IMAGE[positions] " in getView showing "IMAGES cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: 1) That `getView` seems to be outside any class, which will not work. Edit the code to show what class that method is in.
2) Where exactly is it that you call the method `onPostExecute` to generate `IMAGES` inside `getView`? Remember the access you have is only to global class variables (which brings us back to point 1)), variables local to the method, and (I'm not quite sure about this) variables from the methods called by the method you are running at the time you look for a variable. Mind the scoping.
3) Maybe making `onPostExecute` return `IMAGES` would be a good idea?

Comment: yes, i want to return IMAGE from onPostExecute, but i don't know how to do it...

Comment: Well that's easy: change `protected void onPostExecute(Void result)` to `protected String[] onPostExecute(Void result)` and then add `return IMAGES` at the end of the method.

Comment: it can't be change. after i change it, two error is happen. The return type is incompatible with syncTask<Void,Void,Void>.onPostExecute(Void) and Duplicate modifier for the method onPostExecute in type Fragment_Monster.showTask

Comment: Those errors are like Old Teutonic to me :). Try passing an uninitialized `String[]` as an argument and giving it the value of `IMAGES`, maybe that will work. Otherwise, wait for someone more expert than me to answer :). Sorry :).

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry about that warning, I would say. It's only telling you `IMAGES` is never mentioned except where it is declared. I guess your code is not yet complete, otherwise you would not have an unused variable. I bet if you go on writing your code, there will be some point where you will use that variable, and make the warning disappear.

I do not actually understand your code, as `try` and `catch` are constructs I have never used or been taught to use, but finishing the program before minding warnings is a good idea. By the way, once you get to the point of using that `String[] IMAGES` somewhere, save the document, because otherwise the editor might remember the "mistake" and keep warning you.

Comment: "try and catch are constructs I have never used or been taught to use" This is bad news, you *have* to learn exception handling.